# how to change display in gtk.spinbutton

Tags: gtk, spinner

I have a gtk.spinbutton and I want to set the digits according to the locale
format.
like say I have a locale installed hungarian so my decimal separator is
'.'(dot) and thousand separator is ','(comma) eg: my spinbutton value is
1131191 so after the user focus out of the gtk.spinbutton my value should
convert to 11,311.91 . the conversion is made by me but I am not able to set
it to gtk.spinbutton either using set_text / set_value method.

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Formatting a SpinButton can be done by handling the [*output*](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkSpinButton.html#GtkSpinButton-output) signal.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def output(spin):
    digits = int(spin.props.digits)
    value = spin.props.value
    text = locale.format('%.*f', (digits, value), True)
    spin.props.text = text
    return True

spin.connect('output', output)
```

If you also want to let users enter values in the localised format (e.g. let the user type "1,000" instead of "1000"), handle the [*input*](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkSpinButton.html#GtkSpinButton-input) signal.

```
def input(spin, new_value):
    text = spin.props.text
    try:
        value = locale.atof(text)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
    p = ctypes.c_double.from_address(hash(new_value))
    p.value = value
    return True

spin.connect('input', input)
```

(This code is longer than it should be because PyGTK does not properly wrap *input*, hence the ctypes hack. It's just parsing the text and then assigning the numeric value to a pointer location.)

Credits: The ctypes hack and digits formatting are inspired by [Tim Evans's post](http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg16384.html) in the PyGTK mailing list.